# How to toggle Aeroplane mode on/off?in Android device

Tags: process

I want to toggle aeroplane mode on when the network is more then equal to 2point if it is not else aeroplane mode off.every after 10min this loop should be create until the network is more the. 2points. In Android device with 4jelly

Comment: what kind of device are you talking about? I'm sure this is a different process for iphone, android, etc. please update your question with appropriate tags

Comment: Android device jelly bean

Comment: note if you add those tags to your question, you might get some more relevant attention :)